# How do I enable Git for Visual Studio/Team Server 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

We have a Team Project we created in 2013. The web site of the project allows Git Repos to be created, but in Visual Studio 2017 the Git repos we created are always Offline and exhibiting other odd behaviors (loading TFVC's interface in Visual Studio even when connecting to a Git repo within it for example). I used Fiddler to check out the traffic and noticed that this particular project is missing the SourceControlGitEnabled = true flag. A project we created a year and a half later DOES include the SourceControlGitEnabled flag and works properly.

Is there a TFS Team Project setting we can alter/enable or do I have to create a new Project with Git as the repo and migrate everything to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new repo in the Team Project in TFS2013, there should be a warning as below:

> Note that some versions of Visual Studio will only **provide full Team
>   Explorer integration** with a repository that has **the same name as the
>   team project**. Users may need to manually clone this new repository to
>   use it in Visual Studio.

[image]

This maybe the limitation of TFS2013 with GIT, either manually clone this new repository to use it in Visual Studio or create a new Project with Git as the repo and migrate everything to it, both should be work.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I found some more info. The project was initially created in TFS 2013 but they migrated it to TFS 2015, where it is now. I had our TFS team check the database and it seems there is a row for our project in the project_properties table for SourceControlGitEnabled | "True" but it still is not coming back from TFS.

Would this issue be relevant? I do know they changed the name of the project after they created it in TFS 2013. Could that be related to what you mentioned?

Comment: It seems VS 2015 is forgiving about this flag not being set, but VS 2017 ignores Git repos if that flag is not set properly. So we are just now seeing the issue despite it having been there for some time.

Comment: @Bryce The SourceControlGitEnalbed properties tell you source control capabilities in the Team Project. For TFVC which is SourceControlTfvcEnabled. I'm afraid the changed  name of the project  in TFS2013 maybe the issue's root cause. Even though it's in TFS 2015, however it's migrated from TFS2013. There is no other TFS Team Project setting to control source control. And since other project works well on your VS2017. Suggest you to create a new Project with Git as the repo and migrate everything to it as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Patrick again. Last night for a last ditch attempt I tried recreating the default Team. They had deleted that as well. I will talk to our TFS team about migrating. They opened a ticket with MS as well. Thank you very much.